# How can I return the json key id based on given data

Tags: json, perl

Here is a sample of the JSON structure I am working with:

```
{
    "keys": {
      "1": "Name1",
      "2": "Name2",
      "3": "Name3",
      }
}
```

The structure here is "id_number" : "name"

Given someone's name, how can I return their ID number?
If possible, I would like to keep this current structure as I am pulling it from an API and that is the structure presented.

Also, similarly, if the structure was as follows:

```
{
        "id_number": {
          "Fname": "Name1",
          "Lname": "Name2",
          "phone": "number",
          }
    }
```

How could I go about returning "id_number" if given "Name1", "Name2" or "number".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your task exactly is, but if you want to find an id by name here is a code sample:

```
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';

my $json_str = '...';
my $json = parse_json($json_str);
# Get part of JSON with ids and names
my $keys_hash = $json->{'keys'};
# Iterate keys in JSON sub-part
for my $id (keys %{$keys_hash}) {
  # Get name for a specified key
  my $name = $keys_hash->{$id};
  # If found desired name, return id
  if ($name eq $name_to_find) {
    return $id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I have updated my question with another slightly different scenario if you have any ideas on how to do that.